# phpexcel library works fine on localhost but generates blank excel file in server

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

Here is my code that works fine in localhost to generate an excel file with data from database but in hosting server it generates a blank excel file:

```
// Starting the PHPExcel library
            $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
            //$this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory');

            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            // Field names in the first row
            $fields = $query->list_fields();
            $col = 0;
            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
                $col++;
            }

            //format the column sizes 
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $cellIterator = $sheet->getRowIterator()->current()->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells( true );
            /** @var PHPExcel_Cell $cell */
            foreach( $cellIterator as $cell ) {
                    $sheet->getColumnDimension( $cell->getColumn() )->setAutoSize( true );
            }

            //var_dump($query->result());
            //die;

            // Fetching the table data
            $row = 2;
            foreach($query->result() as $data)
            {
                $col = 0;
                foreach($fields as $field)
                {
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
                    $col++;
                }

                $row++;
            }

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');


            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

            ob_clean();
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: That would point to you having the correct dependencies ( modules ) installed on your local server and possibly missing on your hosted server. That would be the first thing to look into.

Comment: also had this problem. couldn't find a solution :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is not related to phpexcel. I faced similar problem earlier and later found that CI's list_fields() function doesn't work in some linux server. You can check this aspect by placing field names statically instead of using this function.